# Why my Microdata has errors on Google Structured Data Testing Tool?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I cannot figure out what is wrong here?
I get error missing location,name,startDate while clearly it is there!
I am using **schema.org microdata**.

The weird thing is that I get 10 valid postalAddress tags like they are not under the main itemscope.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
          <td>
            <a itemprop="url" href="/match/10254">
              <meta itemprop="name" content="SKA Rostov na Donu vs Kuban Krasnodar">
              <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="Russia">
              </div>
              <span itemprop="homeTeam">SKA Rostov na Donu</span> vs <span itemprop="awayTeam"> Kuban Krasnodar</span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td> <small>
            <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2015-09-28T17:00:00.000Z">
            <span>Sep 28 17:00</span>
          </small>
        </td>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the testing tool is clear with error descriptions: you haven't applied required properties. If you add location as Type PostalAddress, so you MUST add address and (stadion)name. 
Location by its own should have its own name too, not only as postalAddress.
And avoid usage of relative urls like urls - they could be not correctly recognized.

**Update**: following markup is validated errorfree:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
          <td>
            <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.website.com/match/10254">
              <meta itemprop="name" content="SKA Rostov na Donu vs Kuban Krasnodar">
              <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
               <meta itemprop="name" content="Stadion Bezimjannyj">
                <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                 <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="Russia">
                 <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="Uliza Lenina 666">            
               </div>
              </div>
              <span itemprop="homeTeam">SKA Rostov na Donu</span> vs <span itemprop="awayTeam"> Kuban Krasnodar</span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td> <small>
            <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2015-09-28T17:00:00.000Z">
            <span>Sep 28 17:00</span>
          </small>
        </td>
      </div>
```

Comment: hi. The url part has no complaint and even if location is not correct (it's not that clear cut) the name and startDate are also off so probably something else if going on.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Need to make sure that the `DIV` is outside of the table or within a table element, otherwise its not valid HTML. Better yet, scrap the table and use DIV styling rather than tables.

Comment: for me i would fully get rid of either table or div and make it like <table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent" itemid="sportevent"><tr><td itemprop="..." itemref="sportevent"></td></tr></table>

Comment: thanks. I realise on top of the address problem there is a problem with tables too I had to change the structure of my html.